# SCCM 2007 Agent deploy problem

Tags: sccm

I have a SCCM 2007 Enterprise Edition on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Edition.My question is;
When I want to deploy by using manually install or push install my agents,
I am receive the following error.I  have not any permission problem.it's turn on the file and printer sharing via GPO.

```
  Trying each entry in the SMS Client Remote Installation 
  accoun list~ $$<SMS_CLIENT_CONFIG_MANAGER><05-06-2011 
  17:59:11.275-180><thread=6200 (0x1838)>

   ---> Attempting to connect to administrative share
  '\\Makina İsmi\admin$' using account 'domain\sccmpush'~ 
  $$<SMS_CLIENT_CONFIG_MANAGER><05-06-2011 
  17:59:11.276-180><thread=6200 (0x1838)>

   ---> WNetAddConnection2 failed 
   (LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS) using account 
  domain\sccmpush (00000775)  $$<SMS_CLIENT_CONFIG_MANAGER>
  <05-06-2011 17:59:11.302-180><thread=6200 (0x1838)>

  ---> Attempting to connect to administrative share
  '\\Makina İsmi\admin$' using machine account.~ 
  $$<SMS_CLIENT_CONFIG_MANAGER><05-06-2011 
  17:59:11.304-180><thread=6200 (0x1838)>

  ---> Failed to connect to \\Makina İsmi\admin$
  using machine account (5)  $$<SMS_CLIENT_CONFIG_MANAGER>
  <05-06-2011 17:59:11.313-180><thread=6200 (0x1838)>

  ---> ERROR: Failed to connect to the \\Makina İsmi\admin$
  share using account 'Machine Account' 
  $$<SMS_CLIENT_CONFIG_MANAGER><05-06-2011
  17:59:11.316-180><thread=6200 (0x1838)>
```

Hope to see your expert advise soon

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a share\account\permission problem. Do the shares exist?  Is the account locked?  Did somebody remove a group from the shares? I'd check the shares first.

Comment: @tony roth - AFAIK,I have not permission problem,but, I controlled again the all permissions.it's not any problem.Any suggestions?

Comment: login to a workstation as 'domain\sccmpush' then try to access \\Makina İsmi\admin$.  What happens?

Comment: also look in the security logs on the "makina ismi" server do you see clientname$ access to it with login errors.

Answer (score 0):

The DOMAIN\SCCMPUSH account needs to be in the Local Admins group on the client machines.

Either add this account to Domain Admins or add it to a new domain security group and make sure new systems get this group added to local Administrators group on the clients.